# How can i check similarity between the rows in a dataframe and add a column as a counter and inc. it when the rows matches?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

Somewhat new to python (Pandas), Please help me resolve this

This is how my dataframe looks like:- 
Device_id is the id of a device which is showing a (Msg) at Time (1524724677), The time is in epoch.

```
  Device_Id    Msg                Time
0  ABC123     connected        1524724677
1  ABC123     connected        1524724679
2  XYZ123     device failed    1524724814
3  ABC123     connected        1524725279
4  XVZ123     device failed    1524725300
5  PQR123      error           1524725325
6  ABC123     connected        1524725345
```

I have to perform operation on each row of the dataframe so that i can add few new columns.

the dataframe i want is will look like:-

```
  Device_Id    Msg                Time       count
0  ABC123     connected        1524724677      1
1  ABC123     connected        1524724679      2
2  XYZ123     device failed    1524724814      1
3  ABC123     connected        1524725279      1
4  XVZ123     device failed    1524725300      1
5  PQR123      error           1524725325      1
6  ABC123     connected        1524725345      2
```

This count column is working as for ex:

Please read all the points to make yourself clear how the count column is working

```
--for row(0) count is (1), bcoz this is the unique device
--we will increase the counter w.r.t (Time)
--we will reset the counter values after every 10 minutes
--for row(1) count is (2), bcoz time (1524724679) is between 
  1524724677 and 1524724677 + 10 minutes.
--for row(2), it is unique device and time(1524724679) 
  between 1524724677 and 1524724677 + 10 minutes  so count is (1).
--for row(3), notice it is not unique device then also it has count=1 
  bcoz, time(1524725279) is not between 1524724677 and 1524724677 + 10 
  minutes. (Count reset)
--for col(4) count is (1), bcoz time (1524725300) is between 
  1524725279 and 1524725279 + 10 minutes.
--for col(5), count=1, unique device and time (1524725325) between 1524725279 
  and 1524725279 + 10 minutes.
--for col(6) count=2, bcoz time(1524725345) is between 1524725279 
  and 1524725279 + 10 minutes.
```

The count values will reset in every 10 minutes that means will start from (1) for each device_id.

after every 10 minutes every unique device_id will be treated as new thats why the count starts again from 1 and maintains its value for next 10 minutes.

Comment: can i do this using for loop, iterating over each row? please help as it is so interesting problem to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby and [`grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) function to solve this problem easily:

```
# convert time
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='s')

# get output
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Device_Id', pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='10min')]).cumcount()+1

print(df)

  Device_Id            Msg                Time  count
0    ABC123      connected 2018-04-26 06:37:57      1
1    ABC123      connected 2018-04-26 06:37:59      2
2    XYZ123  device failed 2018-04-26 06:40:14      1
3    ABC123      connected 2018-04-26 06:47:59      1
4    XVZ123  device failed 2018-04-26 06:48:20      1
5    PQR123          error 2018-04-26 06:48:45      1
6    ABC123      connected 2018-04-26 06:49:05      2
```